# Google authentication with PHP

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am an Windows/Active directory architect with 25 years experience working for a small company.  I am trying to develop a way to manage multiple different authentication systems.  One of them is the corporate gmail accounts. I need to be able to both read and write to gmail using Google's admin API.  I am coding this in PHP, and using mySQL for the database backend. My problem is that I cannot get the php script to connect to Google.  It keeps generating the same error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
 }
}
 in D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\datasync\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\datasync\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\datasync\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(176): Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#2 D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\datasync\src\Google\Http\REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#3 D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\datasync\src\Google\Client.php(798): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...', Array)
#4 D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\datasync\src\Google\Service\Resource.ph in D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\datasync\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118
```

The script is using a service account to connect, and a json credential file.  I have insured the service account has access via the admin console/security/Manage API Client Access:

```
102632896707704106543   View and manage the provisioning of groups on your domain  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group 
View and manage the provisioning of users on your domain  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
```

I have also insured the service account has been activated with domain wide delegation.

I have already searched all over the web looking for a solution to this.

Here is my test script that is generating the errors:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$credentials_file = './redacted.json';

$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);

$client->setApplicationName("webadmin");
$client->setSubject("datasync@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'
]);

$service = new \Google_Service_Directory($client);

 echo realpath(dirname(__DIR__)); 

$userKey = 'cperrine@redacted.com';

$results = $service->users->get($userKey);

var_dump($results);
?>
```

I am missing something, but I don't know what. I have been working on this for a week now and I can't seem to get past it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be a question for the Google developer support. Did you read https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing user authentication step.

Credentials included in your `$credentials_file = './redacted.json';` file authorises request as made by **your application** or project as named in [Google Dev Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). But when you want to create access to someone's data (eg. mails) you need to **authenticate user**. I suggest to use [oauth 2 tech](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) which will allow you to get **user access token** (whole proccess is little complicated but is very secure and allows you to ask user for different permissions over his/her account).

When you have user access token you can set it in Google_Client (as I saw you are using official Google PHP library) like this

```
$client -> refreshToken( $refresh_token );
```

After that any calls to API should be on behalf of user which token belongs to. In my example I used it in Google Analytics

```
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics( $client );
```

Comment: I think I may have been unclear when I posted this.  I am not trying to access the user's mailboxes.   I am trying to access the administration of user accounts. I need to setup, edit and remove user mailboxes.  I downloaded the script from a page online and edited it with my info.  My personal admin account has access to this info via admin.google.com. I can't seem to get the service account to authenticate to do the same thing.

Comment: Could you give link to example you got your script from?